# PHP Connection Class and Execute Scalar Issue

Tags: php, visual-studio, class, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to write a PHP Connection Class that I can reuse easily in our application.

Currently I am working on the Execute scalar command.

I need to return one column and one row.

Here is what I have so far. And yes I know that credentials should be in external file.

I am getting errors:

```
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\mhano00\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\PHPWebProject1\PHPWebProject1\includes\ConnectionClass.php on line 54
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Stack trace:
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP   1. {main}() C:\U sers\mhano00\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\PHPWebProject1\PHPWebProject1\index.php:0
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP   2. ConnectionClass->ExecuteScalar() C:\Users\mhano00\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\PHPWebProject1\PHPWebProject1\index.php:35
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property ConnectionClass::$stmt in C:\Users\mhano00\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\PHPWebProject1\PHPWebProject1\index.php on line 57
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Stack trace:
[08-Apr-2015 08:12:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\mhano00\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\PHPWebProject1\PHPWebProject1\index.php:0.".
```

Here is the Connection Class.

```
 class ConnectionClass
{

private $serverName; 
private $connectionInfo;
public $conn;
private $sql;
private $Result;
private $Rows;
private $stmt;
public function __construct()
{
             $this->serverName = "XXX.XXX.XX.XX";
     $this->connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXXX", "UID"=>"XXXXXX", "PWD"=>"XXXXXX");
     $this->conn  = sqlsrv_connect ($this->serverName, $this->connectionInfo);
     if(!$this->conn === true) 
     {
        //catches error on no connection to database, send auto email error
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     }

}



    //may have to create a dataset within this class to be able to return each type of result.

     public function ExecuteScalar($IncomingSql)
    {
        //select scalar, one cell value is returned
         $this->sql = $IncomingSql;
         $this->stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn, $IncomingSql);


        if ($this->stmt)
        {
            $this->Rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($this->stmt);
            if ($this->Rows)
            {
             $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $this->stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

               return  $this->Result = $this->row[0];
            }
        }

    }

    public function CreateDataSet($sql)
    {
    //create Dataset, araay is returned
    //can be called by this class or from outside to create a dataset array and return it
    $this->sql = $incomingsql;

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
         if ($stmt)
        {
    //return array

        }

    }

    public function SetServer($NewServer)
    {
        $this->serverName = $NewServer;
    }
    public function GetServer()
    {
        return $this->serverName;
    }
 }        
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     }

   }



    //may have to create a dataset within this class to be able to return each type of result.

    public function ExecuteScalar($IncomingSql)
    {
        //select scalar, one cell value is returned
         $this->sql = $IncomingSql;
         $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn, $IncomingSql);


        if ($this->stmt)
        {
            $Rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($this->stmt);
            if ($this->Rows)
            {
             $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $this->stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

                $this->Result = $this->row[0];
            }
        }            
    }


    public function SetServer($NewServer)
    {
        $this->serverName = $NewServer;
    }
    public function GetServer()
    {
        return $this->serverName;
    }


 }
```

Then on the index page I am calling the class like this.

```
$conn2 = new ConnectionClass;
$conn = $conn2->conn;
$car = $conn2->ExecuteScalar('Select * from store');
```

Comment: Your method `ExecuteScalar` is in `$conn2` not in `$conn`

Comment: Fixed and added to question.

Comment: You're getting another error now, not the `"call to undefined method of non-object..."`

Comment: yes...PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property ConnectionClass::$stmt. But I dont see why. From what I see the code looks good.

Comment: May be you're calling `$stmt`property outside the class. and you have also an undefined index on your method `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Got it working.had to change SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC to SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC. There was not $stmt outside the class. i wasn't choosing the correct fetch return type.